# how to merge remote branch of one remote repo to other branch of different project

Tags: git, github

I have projects with name P1, P2 with username u1 on GitHub. P1 has two branches master and pb1. P2 has also two branches master and pb2.
I have cloned the project on my computer with thin command.

```
git clone https://github.com/u1/p1.git
```

If I want to add the branch and data of project P2 and branch pb2 in Project P1.

Which solution is feasible without traditional copy method.

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add p2 https://github.com/u1/p2.git
git fetch p2
git checkout p2/pb2
```